# MVC2 Model Binding - Why do I always get back 01/01/0001 in my DateTime Field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms, viewmodel, model-binding

I have a ThingViewModel with a DateTime property:

```
public class ThingViewModel
{    
  public DateTime ConfigDate{get;set;}
}
```

My view has a reference to a ViewUserControl that it imports and renders, with the textbox for ConfigDate:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ThingViewModel>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Details", 
                         "Things", 
                         FormMethod.Post, 
                         new { id = "SearchForm"})) {% >

  <%= Html.TextBoxFor( Model => Model.ConfigDate ) %>
<% } %>
```

My Index Action has sets the value of the ConfigDate to today:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
ThingsViewMode tvm = new ThingsViewModel
{
   ConfigDate = DateTime.Now.Date
};
 return View(tvm);
 }
```

which is all working just fine.  However, in the Details method when I get the form POST back, all I EVER get back for ConfigDate is the DateTime value of `"01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it the post back that shows you the 01/01/0001 etc ?  or the reply back from the server after

Comment: Post your `[HttpPost]` method. How are you binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was losing the value in a redirect.  Mea Culpa.